# MySQL Table -> How to Shift Column Data to the next Column and bring the last column to the first place (Rotating Columns Data)

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have this problem - where i have (time Schedule) saved in mysql table
the table is for example like this :-

```
+----+--+------+--+--+--------------+--+--------------+
| day |  | Group A  |  |  |  Group B   |  | Group C
+----+--+------+--+--+--------------+--+--------------+
|  sat|  | physics  |  |  |   Language |  | Algebra
|  sun|  | Chemistry|  |  |   Math     |  | Science
|  mon|  | History  |  |  |   French   |  | GYM
|  ...|  | .....    |  |  |  .......   |  |
+-----+--+----------+--+--+------------+--+-----------+
```

So at the end of every month - there is a rotation in the schedule - So the result should be

```
+----+--+------+--+--+--------------+--+--------------+
| day |  | Group A  |  |  |  Group B   |  | Group C
+----+--+------+--+--+--------------+--+--------------+
|  sat|  | Algebra  |  |  |   physics  |  | Language
|  sun|  | Science  |  |  |   Chemistry|  | Math
|  mon|  | GYM      |  |  |   History  |  | French
|  ...|  | .....    |  |  |  .......   |  |
+-----+--+----------+--+--+------------+--+-----------+
```

SO the subjects of Group B is the Subject of Group A ...> See the tables you should understand it better

So it is like rotation of the columns - i have a server side script that will run once at the end of the month to update the schedule

except i don't have any clue of how to achieve this with MySql - also i have a quite large number of groups (32 to be specific )

so any idea to how to reach this result ?

Comment: If you have 32 groups, and each month a single shift takes place, this implies that it would take 2-3 years for a full cycle to occur.  Is this what you intend to happen?

Comment: update tbl set 'group a' = 'group x', 'group b' = 'group a', 'group c' = 'group b' ... but most likely the database design is wrong.

Comment: Yes. Fix your schema design. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: :D Yeah sorry i forgot to say but each 2 groups shift together so they are 16 actually - and also it is not every month Exactly - some times it is every 2 weeks , also it is not a regular year - it is an extended year for medical students in my country (I Know very Disturbing design - that what we handle with unfortunately ) and this is manged by my back end Server so the exact timing is not the problem for me - just the shifting method

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer. Too long for a comment.

An example of a normalised design *might* look like this

```
day  group_ref subject
sat  A         physics  
sat  B         language   
sat  C         algebra
sun  A         chemistry
sun  B         math     
sun  C         science
mon  A         history  
mon  B         french   
mon  C         gym
```

Note however that there is scope here for further optimisation

Comment: Ok - Actually loved this concept - very interesting and i can manage to edit the script to handle this - also i do know that you can shift the rows - so this actually might work , i will give it a try and see